# Android Wear Deployment VS. Mobile Deployment

Tags: deployment, wear-os

I have 2 modules in my project Mobile & Wear because I eventually want to add wear support. I have not done any work to the Wear project, it is just whatever Android Studio generates as part of the project creation template.

I noticed Android Studio creates 2 separate APKs when you do a signed build. I see 1 mobile APK and 1 Wear APK upon signed build.

If I would like to publish only the mobile Module now, and Wear later. Do I just upload the Mobile APK and that's it? Or are there any additional config / code changes necessary?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're developing, there's two different apk's as you said, because each one is used to test the app while we are developing.

Once that you want to submit your app to the market, these two .apk will become just one, calling this process "packaging wearable app".

So, if you want have just your mobile .apk, please go to build.gradle(mobile), and comment the code:

```
wearApp project(':wear')
```

Basically this line is telling to your compiler, to pack your wear app into your mobile app.